# Issue for an Android 12 above - Traditional Chinese Language using AppCompatDelegate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, localization

I'm having an issue for above android 12, setting the traditional Chinese language using AppCompatDelegate.

The rest of the languages working fine.

Here is the code,

```
        val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("zh-Hant")
        // Call this on the main thread as it may require Activity.restart()
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
```

Locale.xml:

```
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <locale android:name="en"/>
   <locale android:name="ms"/>
   <locale android:name="th"/>
   <locale android:name="zh"/>
   <locale android:name="zh-Hant-TW"/>
   <locale android:name="hi"/>
</locale-config>
```

Build.gradle-

```
resConfigs("en", "hi", "ms", "th","zh", "zh-rTW", "b+zh+Hant+TW")
```

GitHub Reference link - https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/PerAppLanguages/views_app

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was -  overriding my attachBaseContext method with updated contextWrapper.
So, I removed attachBaseContext method, and its working fine.

Ensure your activity is extended with AppCompactActivity for the backward compatible APIs that work with the AppCompatActivity context, not the application context, for Android 12 (API level 32) and earlier. Access the backward compatible APIs with Appcompat 1.6.0 or higher.